# select all columns from a table where the combination of 3 fields is unique

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django

i'm trying to select all entries in a table with multiple columns where the combination of 3 specific columns are distinct using django ORM with MySql backend.

| id | first_name | last_name | n_children | some_stuff | other_stuff | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | silver | 2 | any | any | 2021-01-01 |
| 2 | john | silver | 3 | any | any | 2021-01-01 |
| 3 | john | white | 2 | some | some | 2021-01-01 |
| 4 | john | silver | 2 | some | some | 2021-01-02 |

I need to select all rows where the combination of "first_name", "last_name" and "n_children" is unique, prioritizing the most recent entries. In this example, the result should be rows with id [2,3,4].

**what i've tried**

```
qs = Table.objects.all().order_by('-date').annotate(
    unique_value=Concat('first_name','last_name','n_children', output_field=TextField())
).distinct('unique_value')
```

But this does not work because i'm using mysql and i get this error

`django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend`

Comment: One of reason why I change to postgresql. It was not so easy but now I see it was good choice. Postgres have best integration with django.

Answer (score 0):

This actually couldn't be done with `distinct()`. And it probably couldn't be done with Django ORM. Try it with raw SQL:

```py
Table.objects.raw("""
    SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY first_name, last_name, n_children ORDER BY date DESC
""")
```